# how to I make Windows stop complaining about missing python dll?

Tags: python, windows, dll, installation

When I type "python" at the Command Prompt, it pops up a message complaining that "The program can't start because python32.dll is missing from your computer." I have python 2.7 installed, so I think it's looking for the wrong dll... I'm running Windows 7. Any advice?

Comment: You likely have a python 3.2 that didn't uninstall correctly. Try `where python` to see which python your system is using.

Comment: Another way to mess up is to mix Cygwin and native installations in PATH.

Comment: Try reinstalling python 2.7.

Comment: Get the missing dll

Comment: Make sure that python32.dll is in one of the folders in the `%PATH%` environment variable.  If not, you have to add the Python install folder manually.